# Using seq function within dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to compute the number of months between two dates within `dplyr::mutate` but run into the error

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 'from' must be of length 1
```

Is there something about `seq` that is incompatible with `mutate`?

```
library(dplyr)
dset <- data.frame( f = as.Date(c("2016-03-04","2016-12-13","2017-03-01")) , 
                    o = as.Date(c("2016-03-04","2016-12-13","2017-06-02")) )
dset %>% mutate( y = length(seq(from=f, to=o, by='month')) - 1 )
```

Comment: What you are passing to `seq` function is an array and it can only accept single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work around it, you can either use `sapply` or `mapply`. Otherwise, you can extract the month from the date using functions in `lubridate` and then compute the difference.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
# Sapply
dset %>% 
  mutate(y=sapply(1:length(f), function(i) length(seq(f[i], o[i], by="month")) - 1))

# Mapply
dset %>% 
  mutate(y=mapply(function(x, y) length(seq(x, y, by="month")) - 1, f, o))

# function in lubridate
dset %>% mutate(y=month(o) - month(f))
```

Comment: If you're using `lapply`/`sapply` to iterate over indices, it's a sign you should be using `Map`/`mapply`.

Comment: Added it to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to group, iterate, or adjust such that each `from` and `to` parameter is length 1 (`seq(1, 5)` is fine; `seq(1:2, 5:6)` is not), which means `rowwise` or maybe `group_by_all`:

```r
library(dplyr)

dset <- data.frame( f = as.Date(c("2016-03-04","2016-12-13","2017-03-01")) , 
                    o = as.Date(c("2016-03-04","2016-12-13","2017-06-02")) )

dset %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(y = length(seq(f, o, by = 'month')) - 1)

#> Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>            f          o     y
#>       <date>     <date> <int>
#> 1 2016-03-04 2016-03-04     0
#> 2 2016-12-13 2016-12-13     0
#> 3 2017-03-01 2017-06-02     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to also use `dplyr` for this:

```
dset <- data.frame( f = as.Date(c("2016-03-04","2016-12-13","2017-03-01")) , 
                    o = as.Date(c("2016-03-04","2016-12-13","2017-06-02")) )

dset %>% mutate( y = as.numeric(difftime(f,o, units = "weeks"))/4)
```

Answer (score 0):

"alistaire" has done some typo mistake, so the answer is wrong

```
dset %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(y = length(seq(f, o, by = 'month')) - 1)

Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 3 x 3
           f          o     y
      <date>     <date> <dbl>
1 2016-03-04 2016-03-04     0
2 2016-12-13 2016-12-13     0
3 2017-03-01 2017-06-02     3
```